# bash - compare 1 string/column value between two files

Tags: bash, shell

I need to create VG using 1st column value from File1 and File2 if 2nd Column value of File1 equal to File2  . The problem  i face when File1 has more than 
one lunid , please see the below my script but it can't compare  if i have more than

File 1

```
vg1:4314
vg2:4316 4315                      <------------- here 2 lun id 4316 and 4315
```

File 2

```
hdiskpower1:4314
hdiskpower2:4315
hdiskpower3:4316
```

This is what I tried:

```
IFS=":"
while read  vgname Lunid 
do 
while read diskname lun
do 
  if [ $lun == $Lunid ]
  then 
      mkvg -y $vgname $diskname
   fi
  done < File2
  done < File1
```

Expected output is 
        mkvg vg1 hdiskpower1

```
    mkvg vg2 hdiskpower2 hdiskpower3
```

Comment: can you [edit]  and show what is the expected output for this given input?

Comment: Well you're missing an `fi` is the first problem I notice.

Comment: Before the if-statement (or between both while's) you might want to split the Lunid with `IFS=" " echo "${Lunid}"| while read oneLunId; do`. Complicated is testong if `$lun` is a substring of `$Lunid` with something like `[[ "$Lunid" = *$lun* ]]`, you need to rule out matches with 431 and 15.

Comment: A very simple one: `awk -F: 'FNR==NR{n=split($2,a," "); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) vg[a[i]]=$1; next} {print "mkvg", vg[$2], $1}' f1 f2`. It will produce almost what you want, missing joining the same `mkvg vgX` into a single line.

Comment: Thank you fedorqui . I got below output  now

"mkvg vg1 hdiskpower1" 

"mkvg vg2 hdiskpower2"

"mkvg vg2 hdiskpower3"




mkvg vg2  comes twice , It  suppose to be  "mkvg vg2 hdiskpower2 hdiskpower3"